# I want to display a list of words based off different key words

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I want to make a list. Column A are the models. So model1, model2 and model3.

Next to each model is what goes into it. So going along with the picture A3="model" (B3:D3=dog, cat, horse)

When I type the word "Model1" into cell G3 I want it to display the list of items from b3:d3 under neither it. But if I type model2 I want it to display those items instead and so on.

Example these will be on **sheet1**

- A3"model1" b3(dog) c3(cat) d3(horse)

A5"model2" b5(wine) c5(beer) d5(pop)

- Etc.

This will be on **sheet2**

G3"model1"

g4-dog

G5-cat

G6-horse

**or**

G3"model2"

G4-wine

G5-beer

G6-pop

So if I type model2 into G3 I want it to display those items instead going vertical

I was trying a vlookup but could only get it to display 1 cell instead of all 3 items.

This is for Google sheets

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2, Sheet1!A:D, COLUMN(B:D), 0))))
```

[image]